# Complex roots of an irreducible polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

This is a part of a question from a Berkeley prelim exam and I would appreciate a hint, since I can't see a promising approach to this.

Let $p$ be an irreducible polynomial over the rationals with a nonzero complex root $a$. Suppose that $a^2$ is also a root of $p$. How would one conclude from this that for any root $b$ of $p$, $b^2$ is also a root of $p$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: The number $a$ is a zero of the polynomials $p(x)$ and $q(x)=p(x^2)$. Show that this means that $a$ is also a root of the greatest common divisor $h(x)=gcd(p(x),q(x))\in\mathbf{Q}[x]$. What can you say about the polynomial $h(x)$ using the fact that $p(x)$ was known to be irreducible?

Comment: This is easier, if you are familiar with the concept of a minimal polynomial of an algebraic number.

Comment: Right. As $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ is a PID, a variant of Bezout's lemma holds and $a$ is a root of $h(x)$. Since $p$ was irreducible and $h$ cannot be constant, as it has a root, we have $h=cp$ for some nonzero constant $c$. Therefore $p$ divides $q$ and we're done.

Comment: I wonder what you meant by your comment on the minimal polynomial. I am familiar with the material, but I'm not sure how to use it here.

Comment: @MihaHabič: Correct. Instead of Bezout, you can also simply look at Euclid's algorithm computing the polynomial gcd. Explaining the comment: $p(x)$ is the minimal polynomial of $a$ over $\mathbf{Q}$, so automatically any polynomial with rational coefficients that has $a$ as a zero is a multiple of $p(x)$. Here we apply this to $q(x)=p(x^2)$.

Comment: Or in another way: $p$ is the minimal polynomial of $a$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. Hence we have $\mathbb{Q}(a) \cong \mathbb{Q}\left\[x \right\] /(p) \cong \mathbb{Q}(b)$ for every root $b$ of $p$ via $a \mapsto \overline{x} \mapsto b$ and since $a^2$ is a root of $p$ we get $\overline{x}^2$ is a root of $p$ and therefore $b^2$ is a root of $p$ for every root $b$ of $p$.